# How to handle SpriteKit frame rate drop when multiplying by delta time

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I use a common method of multiplying a player velocity in delta time in order to create gravitation effect as follows:

```
  CGPoint gravity = CGPointMake(0, kGravity);
  CGPoint gravityStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(gravity, _dt);
  _playerVelocity = CGPointAdd(_playerVelocity, gravityStep);

  CGPoint velocityStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(_playerVelocity, _dt);
  _player.position = CGPointAdd(_player.position, velocityStep);
```

The problem is that when the frame rate drops (for example - when getting a notification not related to the game)  the player misses the jump, I am guessing due to missed updates, and falls.

Is there a proper way to deal with this usecase?

Comment: Might be easier to understand if you could provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

You are factoring in delta time twice! This is not a framerate drop but your nodes moving faster than they should. Removing the 2nd line should fix it.